# Seeking colloquialism for “just because”

Tags: anglais, oral, conjonctions, argot

I know that “juste parce que” means “just because” but if I wanted to use this as a statement rather than as part of a sentence, is there a colloquial way of saying this?

> Why do you want to go to Spain?
>
> Oh, just because.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest :

> Oh, comme ça.
>
> Oh, juste comme ça.

A possibly cheekier, less idiomatic translation would be :

> Oh, parce que.
>
> Bah, parce que.

Comment: Elaboration on the last part: parce que is used as 'that's why': 'Why do you want to go to Spain?' 'That's why.'

Comment: 'parce que' is way too literal.  'comme ca' is a much better translation.

Comment: @GeorgeM True, edited!

Comment: @mcadorel: *Parce que* is the most idiomatic locution I know of. I don't know why you changed your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can say for instance:

> Pourquoi veux-tu aller en Espagne?
>
> Parce que !

---

**Locution conjonctive: parce que**

(Familier) Marque le refus ou l’impossibilité de réponse à un pourquoi.
*(Familiar) Mark the refusal or impossibility of answering a why.*

> « Mais plaire comment ? plaire… ? plaire pourquoi ? » demanda
>   opiniâtrement le petit boutiquier, qui était sans doute un de ces
>   raisonneurs si communs, incapable de s’élever jusqu’à la logique de
>   l’Absurde.
>
> **« Parce que ! parce que ! »** répliqua la Fée courroucée, en lui tournant le dos. — (Charles Baudelaire, Les Dons des fées, 1869)

Comment: Le redoublement _parce que parce que_, excellent.